# How to iterate through rows using a specified date in a cell?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, conditional-statements, jupyter-lab

[Table 'df'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vdVS.png)

I have a table (see picture attached) and I want to iterate through rows with a condition. If the cell values under EVENT_ID are equal to '10/30/2000,' I want a variable 'count' associated with it which increments by 1 each time the loop with the condition is passed.

I tried the following method:

```
import pandas as pd
count = 0

for rowIndex, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[df['EVENT_ID'] == '10/31/2000']:
     count = count + 1

print(count)
```

But I got an error: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
Tried other methods, too. Still no luck. Is the syntax wrong? If not, what's causing the error? How would we go about doing this task accurately?

Would appreciate assistance! (beginner at pandas and the whole jupyter labs environment)

Comment: Check -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Comment: `df.loc[df['EVENT_ID'] == '10/31/2000']` applies to the whole `df`, not to the row you're looking at, which would be accessed by `row['EVENT_ID'] == '10/31/2000'` instead.

Comment: The question here seems to be"How do I count occurrences of X in a dataframe". That is easy, you don't need a loop. Just `df[df['EVENT_ID'] == '10/31/2000'].count()`. This question sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/.